# jQuery download works in Chrome and not in Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code to download a file to the desk top:

```
    $('#resourceTable tbody').on( 'click', '#getFile', function () {

        var data = resourceTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data.resourseImage

        if (data.resourseImageType === "pdf"){
            a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
        }else{
            a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
        }

        document.body.append(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
    });
```

It works in Chrome. In Explorer the download does not occure and the console message is given:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'append'
resourceAdmin.js (559,10)
```

Line 559 is:

```
document.body.append(a);
```

I have tried:

```
$("document.body").append($(a));
a.click();
$(a).remove();
```

Works in Chrome. In Explorer (no errors) the button turns blue; however, the download popup does not appear.

Comment: `document.body.append(a);` is not supported in IE, use polyfill for that or use any similar method from jQuery as you're already using jQuery, [`jQuery append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thanks Code Manic. I tried "$("document.body").append($(a));" this works in Chrome; however, then I got a similar error in Explorer with "a.remove();" so I replaced it with "$(a).remove();". This works in Chrome; however, in Explorer, no errors, the button turns blue; however, the download popup window is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.appendChild(newElement)`;

or Override jquery append

```
$('#resourceTable tbody').on( 'click', '#getFile', function () {

        var data = resourceTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = data.resourseImage

        if (data.resourseImageType === "pdf"){
            a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
        }else{
            a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.search("Edge") > -1) {
            document.body.append = document.body.appendChild;              
        }

        document.body.append(a); // or use appendChild
        a.click();
        a.remove();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks. Where does this go please, in relation to the other code?

Comment: I have tried your code and the file is not downloaded. The button turns blue and there is no error message.

Comment: `navigator.userAgent.search("Edge")` is might different base on your browser. you should first check in console `navigator.userAgent`

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support downloading that way. you should first convert the data into a blob and use an IE Specific function.
Before line 559. Check whether it's a IE browser and use another method to download which is supported in IE like below-

```
var blob = new Blob([data.resourseImage], {type:  "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"});
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
} else {
    $("document.body").append($(a));
    a.click();
    $(a).remove();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashique, This downloads the file, yah; however, the pdf and jpg files can not be read. I have tried:   `var blob = new Blob([data.resourseImage]);
       if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        if (data.resourseImageType === "pdf"){
     blob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, "application/pdf")
    }else{
     blob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, "image/jpeg")
    }
       return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
   } else {
       $("document.body").append($(a));
       a.click();
       $(a).remove();
   }'`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I can not get it to format properly.

Comment: Hi Ashique, msSaveBlob is non-standard and obsolete. Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob

Answer (score 0):

I have now found, which works with Chrome and IE:

http://danml.com/download.html

Kind regards,

Glyn